# How to check if it's a valid QObject pointer, created by QMetaType::create()

Tags: c++, qt, qobject, qmetaobject, qmetatype

I need to convert `QVariant` to other user custom classes.

All classes have to be derived from `QObject`.

I can check at compilation time the destination type because it's a template but the source is a `QVariant` so, it cannot be checked.

My method:

```cpp
template<class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<QObject, T>::value> > static bool canConvert(const QVariant& var)
```

calls this:

```cpp
QObject* from = reinterpret_cast<QObject*>(QMetaType::create(var.userType()));
```

`from` is never null but, if `userType` is not of a `QObject` base class, `from` is not a valid `QObject` pointer and the call crashes when calling:

```cpp
from->metaObject();
```

I cannot do `dynamic_cast` of a `void*` from `QMetaType::create()`

I tried `qobject_cast` of `from` but it does not fail if it's not valid

How do I know if `QObject* from` is a valid pointer to a `QObject` derived class?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.

If the type is, for example `MyType`, it's pointer type has to be registered.

```cpp
qRegisterMetaType<MyType*>();
```

So, here a rudimental method to check if it's derived from QObject:

```cpp
    static bool isClassDerivedFromQObject(const QVariant& var)
    {
        QString className(QMetaType::typeName(var.userType()));
        className.append("*"); // create a pointer of the name
        const auto id = QMetaType::type(className.toLatin1().data());
        const auto metaObject = QMetaType::metaObjectForType(id);
        return metaObject != nullptr;
    }
```

This can be called before `QMetaType::create(var.userType())`